# python write empty line in the beginning

Tags: python

Im trying to read a gz file and cleanse it(remove all \n and \r) and write it to a new file. But the new file begins with an empty line.

How do I fix it?

My Code:

```py
import json
import urllib
import boto3
import re
import gzip
import os
inputdir='/tmp/bhuvi/'
for filename in os.listdir(inputdir):
    with gzip.open('/tmp/bhuvi/'+file_name, 'rb') as f,open('/tmp/new/custom'+file_name.replace('.gz',''), 'w') as fout:
                file_content = str(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
                fout.write(file_content)

                #read lines from the new file and repalce all new lines 
                #Credits for this piece PMG.COM
                with open('/tmp/new/custom'+file_name.replace('.gz',''), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as log_file:
                    log_data = log_file.read().replace('\n', ' ')
                log_data = re.sub(r'(\'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z UTC)', '\n \\1', log_data)
                newlog = re.sub(r'^\s*$', '', log_data)

                #write the formatter lines to a file
                with open('/tmp/new/cleansed_'+file_name.replace('.gz','')+'.txt', 'w') as fout:
                    fout.writelines(newlog)
```

Comment: By "fix it" do you mean remove the linefeed at the start of the file? You could simply do:
`file_content = file_content.lstrip()`

Comment: Im able to solve this by replacing the last time with `fout.writelines(lines[1:])`

Comment: @Bhuvanesh That is just an inefficient way of doing what I suggested...

Answer (score 0):

You could consume you first iteration of `newlog` by adding these lines before `fout.writelines(newlog)`:

```
newlog = iter(newlog)
next(newlog)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without the file, but my guess is that the empty line is coming from the file you're reading. Make sure that:

- You `strip()` each line after you read it.
- You have an if statement that only writes the line if it's non-null.

Comment: Where to add the strip()? I tried `file_content = str(f.read().decode('utf-8')).strip()` but its not working.